# how to bind dropdown list with grid using jsp and servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm doing my project using Jsp and Servlet. I'm trying to bind dropdown list with grid view, i.e, on selection of option in dropdown list a grid should be populated. I'm not getting it. Can any one help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the dropdown list a name like every other input field,

```
<form action="someServletURL">
    <select name="option" onchange="submit()">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

*(note the JavaScript `onchange="submit()"`, this will submit the form immediately if the dropdown list value is changed; you can of course also leave it away and provide an `<input type="submit">` instead)*

then you will be able to get the selected value by the normal `request.getParameter()` means:

```
String option = request.getParameter("option");
// ...
```

This allows you to prepare data in some servlet based on the selected option. The grid data for example.

```
List<Item> items = createItSomehowBasedOn(option);
request.setAttribute("items", items);
```

Then, in the JSP, you can use JSTL tags to generate HTML the usual way.

```
<c:if not empty="${items}">
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td>${item.id}</td>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)